# How should I structure my nested data for this D3.js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After reading quite a few D3.js tutorials, I'm still uncertain what the best way is to structure data when there are several nested levels. For example, I have a bunch of categories. For each category, I have two years worth of data, aggregated monthly. So, something like this:

```
{"cat1":
        {"2012":[{"start_data":[1,2,3,...]},{"end_data":[4,5,6,...]}],
         "2013":[{"start_data":[1,2,3,...]},{"end_data":[4,5,6,...]}]},
 "cat2":
        {"2012":[{"start_data":[1,2,3,...]},{"end_data":[4,5,6,...]}],
         "2013":[{"start_data":[1,2,3,...]},{"end_data":[4,5,6,...]}]},
 ...
}
```

Every array for `start_data` or `end_data` has 12 items -- one for each month.

I would like to create an interactive chart that looks something like this:

[image: chart]

Since this mockup is terrible... what is going on is that I want the user to be able to select the year (or aggregate), whether they are viewing `start_data` values or `end_data` values (or aggregate, which I neglected to put on the mockup), and the category.

The structure shown above is just meant to show the nesting, for explanatory purposes. I can export it from the database into whatever structure is best for D3.

How should I structure this data for use with D3 and how would I access the data elements within the D3 code?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide a jsfiddle

Comment: The structure of the data really doesn't matter that much. Get an example that does what you want, or write some code yourself, and format the data once accordingly once you have that.

Comment: @jhyap Here's the basic data structure in a jsfiddle. Help accessing/iterating through it with D3 is what I'm looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/2Dswp/4/